# create CheckboxFor from List in View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, checkboxfor

My View Model Class is

```
 public class StudentQuestions
    {
        public int StudentId{ get; set; }
        public int FormId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Questions> Question { get; set; }
    }
```

and question class is

```
public partial class Questions
    {
        public int questionID { get; set; }
        public string field_name { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
        public int qutyp_refID {get,set}
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int ord { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set;} 
        public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
```

}
     in my view

```
@model Test.ViewModels.StudentQuestions
 <table>    
    <tr><td>@Model.FormId</td><td>@Model.StudentId</td></tr>
    @foreach(var q in Model.Question)
    {
        <tr>
          <td> @Html.CheckBoxForFor(i=> i.Question.question)</td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
```

I cant access i.Question.question but I can access in CheckBox, TextBox like following and I want to change Textbox to TextBoxFor and CheckBox to CheckBoxFor and TextBox to TextBoxFor

```
@foreach(var q in Model.Question)
        {   
   <tr>
         @if (@q.qutyp_refID == 4)
            {
            <td>@Html.CheckBox(q.questionID.ToString())
            </td>
            }
            else if (@q.qutyp_refID <= 2)
            {    
            <td>@Html.TextBox("txtDateQuestions", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { style = "width: 120px" }) </td>
            }
            else
            {
            <td>@Html.TextBox(q.questionID.ToString(), null)</td>
            }
        </tr>
}
```

Thanks in Advance.........

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => m.questionID, new { id = @m.questionID, @checked = "checked", Name = "CheckBox" })<span>m.description</span>
```

**Example**

**Model**

```
public class AssignProject
 {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string EmployeesName { get; set; }
        public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Guid? ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string AssignEmployeeId { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
 }
```

**View**

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.IsChecked, new { value = item.EmployeeId, id = "chk_" + @item.EmployeeId, @checked = "checked", Name = "CheckBox" })

     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives error on (i => m.questionID... ) it says cannot convert int to bool

Comment: @Khan Beacuse there is no boolean property in your model and this is just example.

Comment: Give you one example how to bind. @Khan

Comment: I added a boolean variable IsEnabled could you please review the code now...Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jaiman ...Works perfect now ...Could you please advise me for date filed as well   i.e @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> item.questionID,  new { value = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), id ="q" + @item.questionID, Name = "Datet",style = "width: 120px",@class="datepick" }) </td>

Comment: @Khan   try like this

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.questionID, new { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })`

value should be capital like this `Value`

Comment: @Khan  if this ans help you then mark as ans.So it may help other.

Comment: Thanks again Jaimin ...Sorry cant rate the question because I am new to stackoverflow and I need 15 reputations to mark a question and at the moment i have 1 . donno how to get 15 rep ......

Comment: @Khan no prob. Glad my ans help you.